# Re-queue message in Storage Queue-triggered Azure Function - without raising exception

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-queues

I want to build a Storage queue-triggered Azure Function (in python) that does some processing (basically calling some external API) and if that call is not successful, I want to re-queue the message with some delay until a maximum retry count is reached. I can do this just fine, when I simply raise an exception in the Function and it will get re-queued after the time that I specify in the host.json `visibilityTimeout`. The only issue with that is that raising an exception marks the entire Function execution as failed which clutters monitoring etc.

So my question is: Can I achieve the same behavior of using the internal retrying, including dequeue-counter and sending to poison queue in the end, without raising an exception? And without manually cloning the message, sleeping for x seconds and then writing it manually again to the queue.

Most basically I have something like this:

```
def main(msg: func.QueueMessage) -> None:
    logging.info('Python queue trigger function processed a queue item: %s',
                 msg.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
    logging.info('dequeue_count: %i', msg.dequeue_count)
    # Do some more processing...
    raise Exception("Error. Will be retried in a few seconds!")
```

After all, this could also be achieved with Durable Functions. But I need to have a solution in Python and durable functions don't support python as of today.

Comment: You can use an out-binding for the same queue. Create a copy of message and set the enqueuetime. If the copy of your message is null, nothing will happen

Comment: @MarkusMeyer you cannot set Enqueuetime. Plus, as I said, I don't want to copy the message since then I somehow need to track the retry count myself.

Comment: According to my research, When a queue trigger function fails, Azure Functions retries the function up to the times which you set for a given queue message. So I think if you want to the retry policy, we need to throw the exception to make the function fail. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#trigger---poison-messageshttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#trigger---poison-messages